# Move only certain files to GCP and keep subfolder

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to move all the files with extension "gz", with his folder/subfolders of the dir "C:\GCPUpload\Additional" to a folder in the bucket "gs://BucketName/Additional/".

I need to keep the folder structure, in a way like this:

```
C:\GCPUpload\Additional\Example1.gz             --> gs://BucketName/Additional/Example1.gz
C:\GCPUpload\Additional\Example2.gz             --> gs://BucketName/Additional/Example2.gz
C:\GCPUpload\Additional\ExampleNot.txt          --> (Ignore this file)
C:\GCPUpload\Additional\Subfolder2\Example3.gz  --> gs://BucketName/Additional/Subfolder2/Example3.gz
C:\GCPUpload\Additional\Subfolder2\Example4.gz  --> gs://BucketName/Additional/Subfolder2/Example4.gz
```

This is the command that I am using so far:

```
  call gsutil mv -r -c "C:\GCPUpload\Additional\**\*.gz" "gs://BucketName/Additional/"
```

The trouble that I'm having is that all the files are being move to the root of the bucket (i.e `gs://BucketName/Additional/`) , and ignoring its original folder/subfolder

How should I write this? I've tried and googled, but can't find a way where this is working.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing was implemented by gsutil to match the corresponding (older) behavior when you use a recursive wildcard (**) in the shell.

To do what you want you'll need to list all of the objects you want moved and create a shell script that individually runs `gsutil mv` commands that move them to the directories you want. You could probably use local editing tools to make that somewhat easier (like `awk` or `sed`).

Comment: Thanks. But if I create a list, how do I control the fact that only one gsutil mv runs at once, and not all at once?

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that multiple mv operations won't occur as an atomic transaction? That's not possible to do - GCS only provides atomicity of operations on one object at a time.